# Venting Dryer to Outside Through Foundation Wall OR Vent?

Tags: foundation, dryer, joists, venting, exhaust

I'm relocating and replacing the ducting to vent my electric dryer that is located in the middle of my home. I'm using 4" galvanized duct, I've installed a Dryer Box on the back (2x6) wall of my laundry closet in a downward venting position. The vent pipe goes down through the subfloor from the "Dryer Box" and immediately makes a 90-degree turn (elbow) back towards the dryer running in between and parallel with my floor joists. I'm hanging the pipe using galvanized strapping between the joists close to the subfloor (between the subfloor and rolled fiberglass insulation) with a very slight downward angle (1/4" per 5'). As a straight shot, it is 20' to the exterior wall from the elbow.

I've brought the pipe halfway to the exterior wall in a straight run from the elbow. I'm considering two options from here. I was hoping to get opinions on which one is better.

Things to note; it's a single-level home with 8" poured concrete foundation walls. It uses 9.5" i-joists which are hung off the foundation wall (no rim joist)

First option: Continue the straight run and vent directly through the exterior foundation wall using a 4" core drill to make an exit hole. This will place the hole about 2-3" from the top of the concrete. I can't imagine it will affect the structural integrity of the foundation wall but I am concerned about causing future cracking and the potential for blowing out the top (the foundation is 20 years old).

Second option: There is a foundation vent about 40" to the left, two joist bays over from where my pipe is now (which is where the builders had terminated the dryer duct originally using semi-rigid). From the end of my current straight run, I would have to do a 90-degree elbow to the left, drill 4" holes through 2 I-joists and then another 90-degree elbow followed by a straight run, terminating through the foundation vent.

I've checked product literature for the i-joists and it says making 4" holes through the middle of them is acceptable. I'm concerned about making a hole in the concrete but having fewer elbows seems better (not to mention going through a foundation vent looks kind of hokey). I've considered using a product called the "dryer-ell" (made by the same company the makes the dryer box) that claims to not restrict airflow like a normal elbow, however, it still has 2 extra turns and it seems like it would make for easier cleaning later on, keeping it as a straight run.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just because that's where it was doesn't mean that's where it should go. I'll make a hole in a rim joist every time before I have to core a 4" hole through concrete. "two joist bays over from where my pipe is now"  - the bay it's in now, cut the ceiling open and hole saw the rim joist; two elbows and you're done (if it's actually inside the bay, you don't need any elbows)

Comment: For option 1, if the hole is above the concrete, what are you drilling through? Is it the band joist/rim joist which is wood?

Comment: @achoa - the hole would not be above the concrete. The pipe is running in between the joists which are hung (using joist hangers) off the sill plate going down the foundation wall. The i-joist is 9.5" inches tall, sill plate (flat 2x8) is 1.5" leaving 8" of the joists butting up against my foundation wall.. When I started this project I assumed my floor joists sat on top of the foundation wall...unfortunately not the case, otherwise, you'd be correct and I would just drill right through the rim board.

Comment: @mazura - sorry this is a little hard to explain, wish I'd taken a picture when I was down there. No ceiling to cut open, it's single level, I'm working in the crawlspace. Also no rim joist. please see my above comment to achoa. Basically, it's a core drill through a foundation wall or hole saw through two joists and duct it out a foundation vent. either way, it comes out at the same height outside the house (about 10 inches off the ground)

Comment: I fully agree with @mazura going through the rim joist or whatever is sitting on top of the foundation is 100% better than trying to core drill the foundation or going another 40’ and more elbows to a foundation vent.

Comment: I see. While i generally don’t like fighting gravity, there’s certainly dryer duct installations that go through attics and rooftops, so would it be so bad to go slightly elevated and drill through rim joist from the straight shot approach?